# Linked list based on time

Tags: java, datetime, linked-list

Is there a Java API which implements a linked list based on time?

Storing an object in a list, will link it to the time stored and operation like "get the items since time X".

Or do I have to implement it myself with a linked list and Date objects?

Comment: Implement yourself.  LinkedList and Date will do

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, a `Map<Date, Object>` and then search through the `Map` keySet for Date keys greater and build a LinkedList?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I believe he/she wants a `LinkedList<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` will store a DateTime of it's instantiation.  Then he/she wants a method that will get a list of SomeObjects that are from a certain DateTime range.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I feel confident in saying OP wants a Java API where it *just* works. Where "just" and "works" are manifestly obvious. Perhaps some kind of [expert](http://youtu.be/BKorP55Aqvg)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I love this skit.  It's my every day life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to implement this yourself.  You can create a class as so:

```
public class SomeObject{
    public String creationDate;
    public SomeObject(){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
        String creationDate = df.format(today);
    }
}
```

Now you can have a LinkedList of SomeObject:

```
LinkedList<SomeObject> theList = new LinkedList<SomeObject>();
theList.add(new SomeObject());
theList.add(new SomeObject());
//etc
```

Now you'll have to write a method that will loop through the list and find all the objects that have your date/time range requirements.  These will be added to a new LinkedList and returned.